# Passing a vector to grid.arrange as a list of arguments.

Tags: r, function, vector, character, parameter-passing

So I'm trying to use a vector to recapitulate this command, which works well on my data

```
grid.arrange(Sig1.plot,Sig2.plot,Sig3.plot,Sig4.plot).
```

The vector is

```
> Plots.restricted
[1] "Sig1.plot,Sig2.plot,Sig3.plot,Sig4.plot"

> class(Plots.restricted)
[1] "character"
```

However, doing

```
grid.arrange(as.name(Plots.restricted),ncol=1)
```

returns the following error

```
Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
input must be grobs!
```

Alternatively, I tried

```
Plots.reference<-   paste(c(rep("Sig",ncol(Signatures)-1)),c(2:ncol(Signatures)-1),c(rep(".plot",ncol(Signatures)-1)),sep="",collapse=",")
```

where Plots.reference now produces a character vector of length 1.

```
grid.arrange(as.name(Plots.reference)) and grid.arrange(as.symbol(Plots.reference))
```

though continue to return the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 do.call(grid.arrange, lapply(Plots.restricted, as.name))
```

or alternatively:

```
 do.call(grid.arrange, lapply(Plots.restricted, get))
```