# How to pass a vector of ggplot objects to grid.arrange function?

Tags: r, function, vector, ggplot2, parameter-passing

Perhaps the problem has been asked and solved, but the solution didn't work for me.
I wrote a function able to create ggplot objects and return them in a vector. The following is the code inside the function, `vars` is a vector of column names of my data `d`.

```
plotting <- function(d){
    P <- numeric(0)
    vars <- names(d)[!names(d)%in%c('channel','label')]
    for (var in vars){
        p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=channel,y=var)) + 
             geom_boxplot(aes(fill=label)) + ggtitle(var)
        P <- c(P,p)
    }
    return(list(plots=P, num=length(vars)))
}
```

What I want to do is to use the above function to return a concatenated lists `P` consisting of several ggplots objects  as following which is the 'manual' version working fine:

```
p1 <- ggplot()+ ...
p2 <- ggplot()+ ...
p3 <- ggplot()+ ...
pdf('...')
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 3)
dev.off()
```

The purpose of returning `num` is for latter usage in layout arg. of `grid.arrange` function. I have `PLOTS` as returning variable:

```
PLOTS <- plotting(d)
pdf('...')
grid.arrange(PLOTS$plots, PLOTS$num)
dev.off()
```

and I got error:

```
Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  :
input must be grobs!
```

So I tried the solution in [Passing a vector to grid.arrange as a list of arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611441/passing-a-vector-to-grid-arrange-as-a-list-of-arguments)

```
do.call(grid.arrange, c(PLOTS$plots, nrow = PLOTS$num))
```

but still get the same error.
Any comment would be appreciated.

Edit: made problem description clearer, and paste the reproducible data `d` below:

```
structure(list(percent = c(0.0962463533974437, 0.129409967469436,
0.0150265653130588, 0.00299276735619027, 0.0108596845008112,
0.00407417010800106), songs = c(0.231617443342384, 0.430320945945946,
0.109264389042782, 0.282109656611649, 0.0288753799392097, 0.041635687732342
), label = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), channel = c("2",
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2")), .Names = c("percent", "songs", "label",
"channel"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please input `d` as argument to `plotting` and proceed to `PLOTS$plots` to help me for debugging, thank you!

Comment: The elipses in `grid.arrange` expects grobs. Any other parameters you want to pass it need to be named. E.g., `do.call(grid.arrange, c(P$plots, nrow = P$num))`. (Posted as a comment since you don't provide a reproducible example for testing. I'm not sure whether `P$plots` is actually a list, which it must be for this to work.)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I just edited the post based on your suggestion, please have a check. `do.call(grid.arrange, c(P$plots, nrow = P$num))` can't get it worked either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your plotting function has a few problems. First you need to initialize `P` as a `list`. Second, you need to use `aes_string` instead of `aes`, if you want to use the `character` input `var`. And then you have to use `list(p)`, to keep the `ggplot` object intact.

```
plotting <- function(d){
  P <- list()
  vars <- names(d)[!names(d)%in%c('channel','label')]
  for (var in vars){
    p <- ggplot(d, aes_string(x='channel', y=var)) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill=label)) + ggtitle(var)
    P <- c(P, list(p))
  }
  return(list(plots=P, num=length(vars)))
}

PLOTS <- plotting(d)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(PLOTS$plots, nrow = PLOTS$num))
```